# Simple one-to-one setup with Symfony2 / Doctrine2 and primary key thing

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm confused as to all this.

I think Doctrine doesn't allow you to use a primary key on a join (I read it somewhere), but I see here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html that it says "It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys" which seems the opposite.

Anyway, I want to join primary keys, so surely I can do that? I am trying to set up a simple one-to-one relationship. This is what I have but I'm getting various errors that point to this problem.

I can get it set up by joining fields that aren't primary keys but that seems rubbish to me in the case I want to use it for.

I simply want an extra database table to extend the main database table. What's the best way to do this based on any limitations?

I'm using Doctrine 2.2 but can use any version.

The code below is what I would expect to work, but it doesn't allow it.

--

User:

```
user_id # primary
field_1
field_2
```

Extra User Info:

```
extra_id # primary
extra_info_1
extra_info_2
```

User.orm.yml:

```
User:
    type: entity
    table: null
    fields:
        user_id:
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        field_1:
            type: string
        field_2:
            type: string

    oneToOne:
        user_id:
            targetEntity: UserExtra
            mappedBy: extra_id
```

UserExtra.orm.yml:

```
UserExtra:
    type: entity
    table: null
    fields:
        extra_id:
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        extra_info_1:
            type: string
        extra_info_2:
            type: string

    oneToOne:
        extra_id:
            targetEntity: User
            mappedBy: user_id
```

Comment: Best thing you can do is add those error messages to your question

Comment: Error message: "Property 'user_id' in "User" was already declared, but it must be declared only once" - but I don't think that really helps somebody as the problem is more of a 'way to do it' question rather than a 'that error means' problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is incorrect. The id should be under the `id` key not under `fields` and you should never ever write `somethig_id` in an entity. You bind objects together by reference and not database ids. Please read through the documentation carefully.
It is possible to use a primary key as a foreing key in a related entity since Doctrine 2.1: [identity-through-foreign-entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities)

```
User:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO

Address:
  type: entity
  id:
    user:
      associationKey: true
  oneToOne:
    user:
      targetEntity: User
```

Comment: Hello, do you know how to achieve this with annotations ? I put `@id` + `@OneToOne` + `@JoinColumn` [See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339937/ontetoone-identifying-relationship) but it only creates a primary key and no foreign key