# OnteToOne Identifying relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I set up the two following entities:

```
/**
 * Post
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
     */
    protected $id;

    // ...
###################

/**
 * Push
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="push")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Push
{
    /**
     * @ORM\id @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $post;

    // ...
}
```

I know I should persist and flush a Post Entity to be able to persist a push one, that's not the point `:p`.

On `schema:create`, I expected MySQL to create a foreign key constraint on `post_id` in the push table, but all I can see through PMA is a primary key.

[image]

Why ain't there any foreign key created? Did I miss something, I mean is there any annotation flag/option to setup in order to solve this issue?

Comment: @ORM\id @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Post") Maybe problem is here? Is it possible use two annotations in one line?

Comment: @IsaBek This is not a problem, documentation use one-line declaration. By the way separated lines issue the same "problem" `:/`

Comment: Remove @ORM\id from Push, lefting only @ORM\OneToOne

Comment: Also, this is the syntax @JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")

Comment: @KeyneViana One should be able to set the foreign key as a primary key too [doc says](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities). Also, if I remove the `@Id`, Doctrine command issue an error saying «No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "AppBundle\Entity\Push". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key. » (referencedComlumnName is optional. By default, "id" is the default value.)

Comment: What is strange here is that, with some other tables/relations, when primary key is a composed key involving two "ManyToOne" relations, foreign keys are correctly created ! To solve this some people declare another field being the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that the foreign key is created but since it is defined as the primary key as well no other index is needed !
Wee can see the foreign key looking at the "relation view" button above:

```
class Push
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $post;
```

[image]

Hope it will help clarify things ...